# Creating child pandas dataframe from a mother dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows. Actually this dataframe is made by `outer` join of two table.

```
IndentID    IndentNo    role_name     role_id    user_id       ishod    isdesignatedhod   Flag
100         1234         xyz            3         17            1         nan           right_only
nan         nan          nan           -1         -1            None      None          right_only
nan         nan          nan            1         15            None      None          right_only
nan         nan          nan           100        100           None       1            right_only
```

Objective: I want a resultant dataframe based on column conditions. The conditions are given below

```
if ishod == 1 the resultant df will be:
IndentID    IndentNo    role_name     role_id    user_id
100         1234         xyz            3         17

if ishod!=1 and isdesignatedhod==1 the resultant df will be:
IndentID    IndentNo    role_name     role_id    user_id
100         1234         xyz            100         100
```

I am really clueless on how to proceed on this. Any clue will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do approximately what you want

```
nan = float("nan")
def func(row):
    if row["ishod"] == "1":
        return pd.Series([100, 1234, "xyz", 3, 17, nan, nan, nan], index=row.index)
    elif row["isdesignatedhod"] == "1":
        return pd.Series([100, 1234, "xyz", 100, 100, nan, nan, nan], index=row.index)
    else:
        return row


pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(
"""IndentID    IndentNo    role_name     role_id    user_id       ishod    isdesignatedhod   Flag
100         1234         xyz            3         17            1         nan           right_only
nan         nan          nan           -1         -1            None      None          right_only
nan         nan          nan            1         15            None      None          right_only
nan         nan          nan           100        100           None       1            right_only
"""), sep=" +", engine='python')\
.apply(func,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   IndentID  IndentNo role_name  role_id  user_id ishod isdesignatedhod        Flag
0     100.0    1234.0       xyz        3       17   NaN             NaN         NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       -1       -1  None            None  right_only
2       NaN       NaN       NaN        1       15  None            None  right_only
3     100.0    1234.0       xyz      100      100   NaN             NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

To select rows based on a value in a certain column you can do use the following notation:

```
df[ df["column_name"] == value_to_keep ]
```

Here is an example of this in action:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
     'col2': [3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5],
     'col3': [6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8]}
# create a dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

This is what df looks like:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]: 
    col1  col2  col3
0      1     3     6
1      2     4     7
2      1     5     8
3      2     3     9
4      1     4     6
5      2     5     7
6      1     3     8
7      2     4     9
8      1     5     6
9      2     3     7
10     1     4     8
11     2     5     9
12     1     3     6
13     2     4     7
14     1     5     8
```

Now to select all rows for which the value is '2' in the first column:

```
df_1 = df[df["col1"] == 2]

In  [19]: df_1
Out [19]: 
    col1  col2  col3
1      2     4     7
3      2     3     9
5      2     5     7
7      2     4     9
9      2     3     7
11     2     5     9
13     2     4     7
```

You can also multiple conditions this way:

```
df_2 = df[(df["col2"] >= 4) & (df["col3"] != 7)]


In  [22]: df_2
Out [22]: 
    col1  col2  col3
2      1     5     8
4      1     4     6
7      2     4     9
8      1     5     6
10     1     4     8
11     2     5     9
14     1     5     8
```

Hope this example helps!

Comment: All these are already tried. And I am aware of all these.

Comment: Ah I noticed one more thing, you want the first three columns to have the same values in both/all cases. But in your original dataframe only the first row (of the three columns) has the values you want all other values are nan. 
If you make sure all the rows of those columns have the same value, the method I described should work. 
You can try this  running these lines first:
`df["IndentID"] = 100`, 
`df["IndentNo"] = 1234` and `df["role_name"] = "xyz"` 
That way all the rows of a column will have the same value.

Comment: Yes! Thats what I did. In fact you use `df['ishod'].str.contains('1').any()` as a condition and then filter the df as per your logic i.e. `df_2 = df.loc[df['ishod']=='1']`. This would be followed by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Andre gives the right answer. Also you have to keep in mind dtype of columns `ishod` and  `isdesignatedhod`. They are "object" type, in this specifically case "strings".
So you have to use "quotes" when compare these object columns with numbers.

```
df[df["ishod"] == "1"]
```